# How long after a lily scale is planted should I expect a flowering size bulb?

Tags: flowering, bulbs, propagation, lily

I have some Madonna lily bulbs that I would like to scale. If I planted them after the last frost in spring, how long will it be until I get a flowering size bulb? Does it matter which scales I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With good soil and a sunny location and without [lily beetles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_lily_beetle) attacking from scale to a small flower could be three to five years.

Edit: @jmusser asks about a timeline for growth rates.  From [here](http://www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?latinname=Lilium%20candidum)

> Seed - immediate epigeal germination[130]. Sow thinly in pots from
>   late winter to early spring in a cold frame. Should germinate in 2 - 4
>   weeks[163]. Great care should be taken in pricking out the young
>   seedlings, many people prefer to leave them in the seed pot until they
>   die down at the end of their second years growth. This necessitates
>   sowing the seed thinly and using a reasonably fertile sowing medium.
>   The plants will also require regular feeding when in growth. Divide
>   the young bulbs when they are dormant, putting 2 - 3 in each pot, and
>   grow them on for at least another year before planting them out into
>   their permanent positions when the plants are dormant

This mirrors my own experience in growing Lilium canadense from seed.  The first few years all you see is a tiny leaf.  After that it can easily be a few more years until you have a plant with a stem.  Sadly, the local chipmunks liked my seedlings a lot.

Comment: Could you post a reference for *"from scale to a small flower could be three to five years"* ?

Comment: What about from scales, versus seedlings? Shouldn't they grow faster than seedlings?

Comment: Sure, scales should be faster but I could not estimate by how much as it varies by species, planting situation and soil